# Concatenate two arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have arrays of size A `(1, 1, 59)` and B `(1, 95, 59)`. I want to concatenate the arrays. The size of the array should be `(1, 96, 59)`.

```
np.concatenate((A, B),axis =0)
```

Doesn't work. The error is `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: Give us more info, you mean arrays as List, isn't it? if so, I have a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The axis is incorrect:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.ones((1,1,59))
>>> B = np.zeros((1,56,59))
>>> np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        ..., 
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
>>> _.shape
(1, 57, 59)
```